# Take the text up to a specific word

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

```
[text="This is the title"]This is the content of the title[/text]
```

And I'm using regex to take values, such as `This is the title`, but mostly `This is the content of the title`... Of this I can not do it.

Use the following syntax regex:

```
/\[text\s*\=\s*\"([^\"]*)\"\]/i
```

But then I do not know how to take all the text until it finds the word `[/text]`.

Thanks to anyone who helps me.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly that whats your problem?

Comment: @Kasra See the answer of karthik manchala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
\[(text)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"\](.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

Explanation:

- `\[(text)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"\]` you know what it means..
- `(.*?)` capture all characters in a non greedy way
- `\[\/\1\]` followed by literal `[/` and then backreference to first capture group (text) and `]`

And extract values like `This is the title` with `$2` and values like `This is the content of the title` with `$3`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yM1dM7/1)

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I understand where he was wrong. The only thing I noticed you used the `?`, but can not figure out what it does, because if you remove it all works the same. However, thanks again.

Comment: @MicheleLapolla `?` means non greedy match.. it will stop once it encounters `[` otherwise it would match everything till the end.. here you may not notice the difference because of backtracking.. you can experiment it by adding `blablabla` at the end of your string.. Happy to help :)

Comment: You mean like this? [link](https://regex101.com/r/yM1dM7/3). Maybe I misunderstood, but does not change anything anyway. Sorry for disturbing!

Comment: @MicheleLapolla glad that you are experimenting.. check this [link](https://regex101.com/r/yM1dM7/4)