# Backreference does not work in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Lately I've been studying (more in practice to tell the truth) regex, and I'm noticing his power. This demand made by me ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380397/take-the-text-up-to-a-specific-word)), I am aware of 'backreference'. I think I understand how it works, it works in JavaScript, while in PHP not.

For example I have this string:

```
[b]Text B[/b]
[i]Text I[/i]
[u]Text U[/u]
[s]Text S[/s]
```

And use the following regex:

```
\[(b|i|u|s)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/\1\]
```

This testing it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gV7xR5/1) works, the same for JavaScript, but does not work with PHP.

Example of `preg_replace` (not working):

```
echo preg_replace(
    "/\[(b|i|u|s)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/\1\]/i", 
    "<$1>$2</$1>",
    "[b]Text[/b]"
);
```

While this way works:

```
echo preg_replace(
    "/\[(b|i|u|s)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/(b|i|u|s)\]/i", 
    "<$1>$2</$1>",
    "[b]Text[/b]"
);
```

I can not understand where I'm wrong, thanks to everyone who helps me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because you use a double quoted string, inside a double quoted string `\1` is read as the octal notation of a character (the control character SOH = start of heading), not as an escaped 1.

So two ways:

use single quoted string:

```
'/\[(b|i|u|s)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/\1\]/i'
```

or escape the backslash to obtain a literal backslash (for the string, not for the pattern):

```
"/\[(b|i|u|s)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/\\1\]/i"
```

As an aside, you can write your pattern like this:

```
$pattern = '~\[([bius])]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/\1]~i';

// with oniguruma notation
$pattern = '~\[([bius])]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/\g{1}]~i';

// oniguruma too but relative:
// (the second group on the left from the current position)
$pattern = '~\[([bius])]\s*(.*?)\s*\[/\g{-2}]~i';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not think I made a mistake like that. However I tried to use the pattern with ~ (who did not know to tell the truth), but does not work is not it
But it does not work for everyone, or am I wrong? [link](https://regex101.com/r/gV7xR5/2)

Comment: However, could you explain briefly (if not a disorder), the difference between `/` and `~`?

Comment: @MicheleLapolla: you are free to choose the pattern delimiter you want (http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), to avoid to escape the literal slashes in the pattern, `~` is a better choice. The three patterns work well, you can check them here: https://eval.in/368317

Comment: Thanks, I was getting the SOH character in output and had no idea what it was.