# PHP Regex reduce a repeated character to a single instance

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to rid a text for repeated exclamation marks (!!!), question marks (??) or full stops (....) and replace them with a single instance of themselves. So I need "one preg_replace to rule them all" basically.

I currently have three separate patterns being executed:

```
preg_replace("/[!]{2,}/","!", $str);
preg_replace("/[?]{2,}/","?", $str);
preg_replace("/[.]{2,}/",".", $str);
```

Is there a way to replace the found character with a single instance of itself using just one regex pattern?

I need to turn:

```
Ok!!!
Really????
I guess.....
```

into:

```
Ok!
Really?
I guess.
```

With one regex pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a capturing group with a backreference:

```
([?!.])\1+
```

Replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Cp7XSV/2)

**Details**

- `([?!.])` - matches and captures into Group 1 a single char: `?`, `!` or `.`
- `\1+` - matches one or more instances of the content captured into Group 1.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NgPkWz):

```
$str = "Ok!!!\nReally????\nI guess.....";
$res = preg_replace('/([?!.])\1+/', '$1', $str);
echo $res;
```

Results:

```
Ok!
Really?
I guess.
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! For ages it wouldn't work for me but I found it only works with single quotes in the code? With double quotes the pattern didn't match for some reason. Anyway, its great.

Comment: @Hasen: See the [Backreference does not work in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383383). Inside double quotes, you need to double the backslashes.

Comment: Oh I see...interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Just for completion, I thought I'd post my own answer based on my original code after viewing the answer given by another.

```
 pattern ([!?.]){2,}

 preg_replace('/([!?.]){2,}/','$1', $str);
```

This pattern also seems to work fine.

Comment: Be carefull, that doesn't do the same thing than other answer. This will replace `.!!.??` with `.` but may be is that what you want.